# Issue when running spark program in EMR 5.13.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

We are able to run the spark programs in emr 5.9.0 without any issues. But getting the below error when running in emr 5.13.0.

```
19/11/12 07:09:43 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
```

I have added the below dependency in maven. But still getting the same issue. Can anyone please help to fix the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EMR 5.13.0 has spark version `2.3.0` while EMR 5.9.0 has `2.2.0`. Try to upgrade spark version in your jar.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue after adding the below.

--jars xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar,xml-apis-1.4.01.jar

Thanks